# How can I fix a rownames error in the as.mids function?

Tags: r

I'm experiencing an error using the function `as.mids` in the package `mice` (v3.5.0) for R v3.6:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': '1', '2', '3', [...]
```

Here's some background:

I'm using multiple imputation for covariate data. I imputed the missing covariate data, then saved the result as a data frame in long format:

```
imputed <- mice(raw.data,...)

mydata <- complete(imputed, "long", inc = TRUE)
```

I tried to convert the data frame to a mids object for analysis.

```
mydata <- as.mids(mydata)
```

However, this resulted in the error above.

I don't understand the message because the dataframe doesn't have rownames (I checked with `rownames(mydata) <- NULL)`.

I appreciate any advice.

**Update** The package manual states:

> The function expects the input data long to be sorted by imputation
>   number (variable ".imp" bydefault), and in the same sequence within
>   each imputation block.

So I tried `newdata <- mydata[order(mydata$.imp,mydata$.id),]`, then `as.mids`. The same error message results.

Comment: Sorry, it seems to me you don't know much about multiple imputation, and that the analysis you're about to do doesn't make sense. Provide **1.** complete `mice()` call, **2.** information and code of planned analysis, **3.** example data, provided in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I imputed data for men and women separately and combined the rows of the data frames after I called complete(...,action=long). The `.id` variable did have repeats because it was a vector of 1:nrow for men and 1:nrow for women. I recoded the `.id` variable to correspond to individual id and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this error is also introduced when the tmerge function from the survival package is used to structure your long-formated data from the MICE package for analysis with time-varying covariates. This error occurs because tmerge duplicates the .id values from the "primary data set" (data1 in tmerge). It can be solved in the same way as outlined by TJ87, for example:

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt[order(dt$.imp,dt$.id),]
unique_obs <- dt_mice_long$.id %>% unique %>% length
dt$.id <- seq(from = 1 , to = unique_obs)
```